# Passing array to form as hidden "key" is lost

Tags: php

This is my array

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz', 'bat' => 2);



<form method='POST' action='test.php' onsubmit='return validateForm()' >
echo '<input type="hidden" name="array" value= "'.implode(',', $array).'">';
echo "<<input type='submit' name='Submit'  value='submit' />";
echo '</form>';


$arry = explode(',', $_POST['array']);
```

I am getting key as `0,1,2`. Which should be "foo", "baz", "bat".

How can I get correct key?

Comment: Where are you posting your array? I only see `$_POST['test']` instead of `$_POST['array']` in your `test.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am wright, you need the array keys after the posting the form with imploding the array values.

I think, `json_encode` is a good solution. I am adding another solution.

Add another hidden element which will post array keys with array values.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="values" value= "'.implode(',', array_values($array)).'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="keys" value= "'.implode(',', array_keys($array)).'">';
```

In your `test.php`

```
$arrayValues = explode(',', $_POST['values']);
$arrayKeys = explode(',', $_POST['keys']);

$yourFinalArray = array_combine($arrayKeys, $arrayValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your array and decode using, for example, `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions.

Function `implode` is ignoring the array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is something wrong. Yuo are exploding an array while you should implode it. Also you cannot retrieve `baz` as key since it is a value. It's key is actually 0, have a look at this sample

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz', 'bat' => 2);
$arry = implode(',', $array_key($array));
echo $arra;
```

This will transform you array's key in a comma separated value list

```
foo,0,bat
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/NuEXEW)

In the other way if you will get values from your post array you will get

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz', 'bat' => 2);
$arry = implode(',', $array_values($array));
echo $arra;
```

Output

```
bar,baz,2
  //^ as you can see baz it's between values
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/dzwf2l)

Comment: I am getting the values however I also would like to key. like "foo",0,"bat"

Answer (score 0):

don't use `’`, use `'` or `"`, in your array i see that it will be look like this -> `array(3) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" [0]=> string(3) "baz" ["bat"]=> int(2) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array in form submit as

page1.php

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz', 'bat' => 2);

echo "<form method='POST' action='page2.php' onsubmit='return validateForm()' >";
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
echo '<input type="hidden" name="array[]" value = "'.$key."|".$value.'">';
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='submit' />";
echo '</form>';
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$array = array();
foreach($_POST['array'] as $value) {
    $a = explode("|",$value);   
    $array[$a[0]] = $a[1];
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [0] => baz
    [bat] => 2
)
```